# When does PHP-FPM process release memory?

Tags: php

I am trying to configure our server cluster to handle large spikes in traffic.  What I have noticed is when we get a spike we get a lot of failures due to PHP-FPM having to spawn a lot of workers quickly.

I can offset this by setting start_servers higher so the PHP-FPM processes are already ready but now this gives me some RAM management dilemmas.

On a test server with just me and some crons using it I load up a load of workers and watch the ram.  Over time the PHP-FPM processes start to steadily increase in ram.

Why is there RAM left allocated inside the worker?

I am trying to understand why these processes gain ram and then just keep it.  What is that RAM and when exactly does PHP-FPM recycle it?